# set z-index to the auto suggestion angular mention list

Tags: css, angular7, mention

I am working with Angular 7.

I am facing a problem in setting the z-index to the list of the user that are coming with auto-suggestion.

I am using a text box in which if I type `@` then it will give suggestion for all the available users.

for this functionality, I am using Angular mention directives but I am not able to set z-index when all users are coming.

I want to set up z-index to the coming user's list so that it should not hide. it should come and show the complete list.

below is my code that I am using for auto-suggestion with Angular mention directives.

```
<textarea #cName cols="30" [mention]="items" [mentionConfig]="{ labelKey:'name'}" rows="1" style="z-index: 1 !important"></textarea>
```

css file:

```
textarea {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

with the above code, it is giving the following result attached in the below image.[image]

So in the above image, we can see that the list is hiding behind the accordion but I want to see the complete list of the users.in the code, I have applied z-index in the styles but it is not working.

can anyone help me to come out of this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you please send me stackblitz link.

Comment: I don't have stackblitz link. but you can refer this link of angular mention: http://dmacfarlane.github.io/angular-mentions/

Here if you type @ then it will give the suggestion of the users. but in my case the list is hiding.

Comment: Could you paste the css for the <textarea> and for the list?

Comment: please see the above-edited post I have pasted the CSS for the text area. I am not using any CSS for the list.

it is a library named Angular-mention.

Comment: the `.dropdown-menu` css class has already a z-index of 1000, is your following content having a higher z-index ? In anyways, try setting a higher z-index for that css selector

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha yes I have checked that on angular mention's inspect element, in my local inspect element z-index is not set at 1000px and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The css on the <textarea> has no effect on the dropdown menu. And if you want to create a custom stacking order, you can use the z-index property on a positioned element(relative, absolute, fixed and sticky). Not a static positioned element which is default. In the link you posted they have applied css to the dropdown menu. I don't know if this is the default css or if it's a custom css for the demo, but try to apply these styles and you should be good to go.
Se screenshots below
https://pasteboard.co/IbUeuM3.png https://pasteboard.co/IbUfhie.png

Comment: @henrik123 yes I tried to implement that CSS also by defining a class. I think it is generated CSS. because I am also applying the same thing but couldn't able to do till now.

Comment: So just add it in your css file

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha for that list I don't have any CSS file, I think it is generated CSS. is there any way how to define that CSS in my local.

Comment: just add it in your component stylesheet file or the global app css file